# Проблема с кодировкой Python

Tags: python, utf-8, pycharm

```
# coding: utf8

print "Привет"

#выводит:
РџСЂРёРІРµС‚
```

Использую **PyCharm**. Раньше вывод был нормальным, возможно, после обновления **PyCharm**, перестало выводить русские буквы. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Для кодировки UTF-8 следует написать так

```
print u'Привет'
```

Comment: а почему неделю назад я писал без 'u' и все работало? и есть ли другой способ писать русские комментарии?

Comment: Может у вас формат записи файлов поменялся в программе?

Comment: я в этом профан) все может быть. намеренно я ничего не менял, возможно обновление что- то изменило. подскажите, как исправить этот вопрос?

Comment: Какой формат записи файла у этого примера?

Comment: .py или что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Извините, кодировку файла имел в виду :)

Comment: понятия не имею) как это можно выяснить?

Comment: Обычно в современных редакторах кодировка текста указывается. Или внизу рабочей обрасти в статистике, или в меню выбора кодировки. Если в вашем редакторе такого нет, то можно попробовать Notepad++.

Comment: notepad++ говорит "UTF-8 w\o BOM". я, собственно, не могу понять, в чем проблема. работаю с одним и тем же проектом и в один прекрасный день он перестает воспринимать русские комментарии.

Comment: Есть тут статья http://habrahabr.ru/post/117236/ в которой человек боролся к кодировками в Windows. Посмотрите, может поможет. P.S. И откатите PyCharm до предыдущей версии с которой работали раньше. Для проверки.

Comment: может быть не заморачиваться и писать все через 'u'?)

Comment: Я сам профан в Python, так что не отвечу на этот вопрос. P.S. Еще попробуйте файл примера сохранить в кодировке  "UTF-8 with BOM", а не в  "UTF-8 w\o BOM".